Is the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources file published somewhere?
For context, I am installing Ubuntu through debootstrap, and so far I have been copying the sources from my build machine. Now, I need a way to handle installations of versions of Ubuntu different from my build. I understand that it is fairly easy to build the sources file from scratch, but are there any official or third party repos that host the sources file online?

https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

The sources file varies slightly on product & release, and includes localized/regional differences that are prepared at install time (region isn't known until then!); so there isn't a single file.  You ask "are there any official" for which official archive mirrors are found at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors

@kyodake repogen website hasn't been updated since 18.04, so it no longer supports any currently suppported version of Ubuntu.

@karel: Since the user requires: installations of versions of Ubuntu different from my build,generated sources.list for Bionic, you should just change the file, bionic to the version you want to use.

@kyodake Thanks for reminding me. In case you want to do it that way an up-to-date example for Ubuntu 24.04 is in this answer.
